# Removing rows from dataGridView-using dataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to remove all the rows to reload them (I need to remove all rows)  For some reason its not removing them from my datagridview (tho its not adding any extra either) nothing is happening. I have tried many different methods, I know I have done this in the past. (maybe because its end of the day)

Here is my code trying a whole bunch of removes

```
       private void loadMSXGridView()
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        dgv.DataSource = null;
        dgv.Refresh();
        bs.DataSource = GetTable();
        dgv.DataSource = bs;
        dgv.Columns[0].Width = 391;
        dgv.Columns[1].Width = 30;
    }

        private DataTable GetTable()
        {
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            t.Rows.Clear();
            t.AcceptChanges();

            t.Columns.Add("Accounting Line", typeof(string));
            t.Columns.Add("#", typeof(string));
            foreach (AMAPnr.RemarkElement re in AMAPnr._RemarkElements)
            {
                if (re.ElementID == "RM" && re.FreeFlow.StartsWith("*MS"))
                {
                    DataGridViewCell gridCellText;
                    DataGridViewCell gridCellElement;

                    gridCellText = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                    gridCellText.Value = re.FreeFlow;

                    gridCellElement = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                    gridCellElement.Value = re.ElementNo.ToString();

                    t.Rows.Add(gridCellText.Value, gridCellElement.Value);
                }
            }
            return t;
        }
```

My delete button calls loadMSXGridView, I only need to refresh everything because the items in my datagridview are associated to an element number, which won't remain the same

Comment: Why don't you make use of another BindingSource and associate that to the grid?         
 BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
 bs.DataSource = YourSource;

  dgv.DataSource = bs;

Comment: @HelloWorld updated in question, I haven't test as it takes a while to compile, should it just work? or should I use a different method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, everything worked after running a throughough debug I found
The remarks elements were not being deleted, thus it was getting deleted by adding the same items back in. I remove the items from the RemarkElement section and it works, thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Initially, you are data-binding:

```
dgv.DataSource = GetTable();
```

you should then *continue* data-binding; either tell the *table* to clear itself (and repopulate the data), or just assign a *different* data-table to `dgv.DataSource`.

Comment: I tried to set dgv.DataSource to null as loadMSXGridView() is the method called after the select to delete a row or should I do a completely blank table?

Comment: @Spooks I'd do an empty one (not that I use DataTable much)

Comment: I'll give it a try, what do you usually use?

Answer (score 1):

In my limited data binding experience it is not easy to edit a data source.  You should handle your data edits using one of the row binding or other events.  However if you want to edit a datasource you basically have to clone the structure, then import the rows.  So in this sense you should actually go back to your datasource and select exactly what you want.

However..

If you want to filter / edit your data here is how you can do it:

```
    DataSet ds1 = [Your Data Source]
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

ds2 = ds1.Clone();

for (int i = 0; i < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() != "SomeValue")
    {        
        ds2.Tables[0].ImportRow(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]);
    }
}
ds1 = ds2;
```

Comment: I used a DataTable which is very similar but I had to reset the datasource so mydgv.DataSource = table2;

Answer (score 1):

If you simply just want to add a different datatable as the datasource, then do:

```
datagridview.DataSource = datatable;
datagridview.Invalidate();
```

That should work, as I have just done the exact same thing on a project i'm working on at the minute  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set the DataSource of your DataGridView to a BindingSource and change the DataSource of the BindingSource instead:

```
var table1 = GetDataTable();
var bindingSource1 = new BindingSource(table1, null);
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;


// after reload
var table2 = GetDataTable();
bindingSource1.DataSource = table2;
```

that solves most problems, since you don't have to worry about how your data is bound.